# How to create custom header before request in WCF web service C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I want to integrate bluesuit (`https://docs.bluesuit.com/?shell#send-document`) in C#. I want to upload a `.pdf` to bluesuit by setting `Content-Type` and `Authorization Bearer` using a WCF service. How to add this in header and call `https://docs.bluesuit.com/?shell#send-document` post method and get response and integrate bluesuit in C# with WCF?

Simply I just want to call a third party (bluesuit) post url in wcf service and get response from this third party (bluesuit) post url so how to call this third party post url in a WCF method?

Thanks in advance. need help please advice.

Comment: Taking a quick look at the docs, it does not appear they have a WCF service. Their api is REST.

Comment: i am new in wcf service so is it possible to create wcf service dll which contain uploadpdf method which call the bluesuit upload method ?

Comment: Do you mean you have a WCF service, and you want to call their API within an operation of your service?

Comment: Forget about WCF. You will call their api with System.Net.HttpClient, or RestSharp or Flurl or similar.

Comment: yes i want call their apis in wcf method

Comment: You can use the APIs I mentioned from within a wcf client. There will be no difference in the code than if you were calling the API from any .NET project. It sounds like you think you need to send a SOAP request to the API, but that is not the case - is is not a soap service.

Comment: so is it posible to make wcf service soap type

Comment: @ketan I think you are confused. The fact that you are calling the API from a WCF application is irrelevant. You do not need to make SOAP requests *from* your service and in fact, to use this API, you cannot. Forget about SOAP, just code it like any HTTP request you would normally do in any .NET application.

Comment: The situation is I have client which is running his service in WCF ok now they want a upload pdf with bluesuit. So I am thinking of to create a service in WCF which is work as a patch like DLL

Comment: If you want to customize the message, you can take a look Messageinspector:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/message-inspectors

Comment: thank you for valuable reply how to call upload file url in wcf method and get response with customize header which contain common declare auth token

Comment: i just want to call a third party post url in wcf service and get response from this third party  post url so how to call this third party post url in wcf method ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```cs
// Code to get a static WebClient
private static WebClient GetWebClient
{
    get
    {
        var client = new WebClient
        {
            BaseAddress = "https://docs.bluesuit.com/?shell#send-document",
            UseDefaultCredentials = true
        };
        client.QueryString.Clear();
        client.Headers.Clear();
        client.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/pdf");
        return client;
    }
}
```

Usage inside your function where you need to get response from bluesuit:

```cs
var client = GetWebClient;
// getToken() call returns you the Token as a string
client.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + getToken());
var data = "Your data goes here";
var response = client.UploadString(url, "POST", data);
```

Process the response as per your use case.